# Cannot add scene strip in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

I want to add a scene strip in the Video Sequence Editor but the list of scenes is empty despite a scene existing and having a camera. See the image below. Can it be some bad combination of settings or is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: IIRC they removed the ability to add the current scene as a strip. Try from another scene?

Comment: @3pointedit You are correct. If you make it an answer I accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devs removed the ability to add the current scene as a strip. Try from another scene.

Comment: As a sidenote, do you know why did they do it? It's very inconvenient, switching between multiple scenes all the time while adjusting the objects' positions.

Comment: I don't recall as I really liked it for camera switching the current scene. Perhaps in Blender 2.8 you will be able to edit different scenes per window instead of switching?

Comment: Stumbled on the same issue.
However there's an easy workaround: create a new scene as "Linked Copy", this will mirror changes live from the base scene, then only the main scene has to be edited.